# GCP Cloud Functions fails with 'connection error' or 'crash' when received HTTP response with XML body

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, xml-parsing, google-cloud-functions, docusignapi

I am trying to send an HTTP POST response with XML body from Docusign Connect to GCP cloud functions using Python SDK.

While the response comes, the cloud functions gives the following error every time.
**Function execution took 59 ms, finished with status: 'connection error'** or
**Function execution took 59 ms, finished with status: 'crash'**

The function doesn't even start working. Please help me solve this problem.

Also, I am not sure how to parse the XML response that I receive from external source. I didn't find anything in the documentation.

Comment: Add to the question the output of the command `gcloud beta functions describe [FUNCTION-NAME]` and the code of the function.

Comment: Hi Juan.. Thank you for responding.. I have solved the issue.

Comment: @KshitijBhadage you can answer your own question, so that others can benefit from your knowledge

Comment: Hey Hack5... I have already answered my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved the above issue on my own. The problem was with parsing the XML request. I parsed it using xmltodict method.

Please find the sample code to parse the XML body.

```
import logging
import xmltodict

def main (request):
    data = xmltodict.parse(request.data)
    logging.info(data)
```

Comment: "Hi! Good work finding the solution! Can you [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/)? It will make it more visible and help someone with the same issue as you find the solution. Thanks!